# Fetching and displaying data with React

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, jsx

i am new to react and have been trying this for a long time without any success. Maybe someone could look through and determine the mistate i am making. here is my code. 
I have the App.js file with a route to services page where i want to fecth and display data divs with services from a mysql database with react and JSX.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Header from "./Header";
import axios from "axios";

class Services extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      services: [],
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/services")
      .then((response) => this.setState({ services: response.data }));
  }

  render() {
    var { services } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Header></Header>
          </BrowserRouter>
          <div className="Services">
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <h1 className="text-center title">Our Services</h1>
            <p className="p-3 text-left">
              Quickly get help for your issue by selcting the service that
              matches your issues. You can always describe your issue if it does
              not match any of our services and you only pay when the issue has
              been resolved.
            </p>
            <hr></hr>
            {services}
          </div>
        </div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Footer></Footer>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Services;
```

Comment: what are you trying to achive with `<BrowserRouter>
            <Header></Header>
          </BrowserRouter>`

Comment: services is an array. You should try to use the function map for displaying data, don't write directly {services} in JSX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

class Services extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.setState({ data: response.data });
    });
  }

  render() {
    let services_data = [];

    this.state.data.forEach((res, i) => {
      services_data.push(
        <ul key={res.i}>
          <li>{res.id}</li>
          <li>{res.title}</li>
          <li>{res.body}</li>
        </ul>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <BrowserRouter>Header</BrowserRouter>
          <div className="Services" />
          <div className="row">
            <h1 className="text-center title">Our Services</h1>
            <p className="p-3 text-left">
              Quickly get help for your issue by selcting the service that
              matches your issues. You can always describe your issue if it does
              not match any of our services and you only pay when the issue has
              been resolved.
            </p>
            <hr />
            {services_data}
          </div>
        </div>
        <BrowserRouter>Footer</BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Services;
```

The above code is working fine and split the method like this.